# get pthread_t from thread id

Tags: linux, pthreads

I am unable to find a function to convert a thread id (`pid_t`) into a `pthread_t` which would allow me to call `pthread_cancel()` or `pthread_kill()`.

Even if pthreads doesn't provide one is there a Linux specific function?
I don't think such a function exists but I would be happy to be corrected.

### Background

I am well aware that it is usually preferable to have threads manage their own lifetimes via condition variables and the like.

This use is for testing purposes. I am trying to find a way to test how an application behaves when one of its threads 'dies'. So I'm really looking for a way to kill a thread. Using `syscall(tgkill())` kills the process, so instead I provided a means for a tester to give the process the id of the thread to kill. I now need to turn that id into a pthread_t so that I can then:

- use `pthread_kill(tid,0)` to check for its existence followed by
- calling `pthread_kill()` or `pthread_cancel()` as appropriate.

This is probably taking testing to an unnecessary extreme. If I really want to do that some kind of mock pthreads implementation might be better.

Indeed if you really want robust isolation you are typically better off using processes rather than threads.

Comment: I don't think you can. Anyway this may help you out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/how-can-i-kill-a-particular-thread-of-a-process

Comment: `pthread_kill` doesn't kill a thread, it sends a signal (and it can bring down the entire process). Anyway, why on earth do you even deal with kernel thread ids? They are not even exposed by glibc.

Comment: A pthread_t is opaque so there is no way I can specify a specific thread to terminate. However, ps or top -H can show the thread ids from the command line.

You can set the signal mask so that signals only go to specific threads. In this case pthread_kill() might be handled safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such a function exists but I would be happy to be corrected.

As a workaround I can create a table mapping `&pthread_t` to `pid_t` and ensure that I always invoke `pthread_create()` via a wrapper that adds an entry to this table. This works very well and allows me to convert an OS thread id to a `pthread_t` which I can then terminate using `pthread_cancel()`. Here is a snippet of the mechanism:

```
typedef void* (*threadFunc)(void*);

static void* start_thread(void* arg)
{
  threadFunc threadRoutine = routine_to_start;
  record_thread_start(pthread_self(),syscall(SYS_gettid));
  routine_to_start = NULL; //let creating thread know its safe to continue
  return threadRoutine(arg);
}
```

Comment: What if the tid was recycled? The map should be aware of that and have the updated pair, I assume. Then I need to intercept every place where the pthread_create might occur?

Comment: Yes record_thread_start() would handle that. This assumes you have control over all threading concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Sensible conversion requires there to be a 1:1 mapping between pthread_t and pid_t tid, which is the case with NPTL, but hasn't always been the case, and won't be the case on every pthread platform. That said...

**Two options:**

**A)** override the actual `pthread_create`, using `LD_PRELOAD` and `dlsym`, and keep track of each `pthread_t` and their corresponding `pid_t` there. To get the thread `pid_t` you can either take advantage of the pthread private headers to de-opaque the pthread_t and access the pid_t inside there, or if you want to stick to documented APIs `pthread_sigqueue` each `pthread_t` thread as it is created and have a `sigaction` signal handler call `gettid` and pass you back the thread `pid_t`, with appropriate synchronisation between your new `pthread_create` and the signal handler[1].

**B)** You can read the all of the thread `pid_t` from `/proc/<process pid_t>/task/`. Then use the `SYS_rt_tgsigqueueinfo`[2] `syscall` to implement a new function `thread_sigqueue`, a pid_t variant of `pthread_sigqueue` so that you can signal the `pid_t` thread, and from the `sigaction` signal handler call `pthread_self` passing out the value with suitable synchronization, etc.

**Notes:**

**1** - I think it's worth writing 2 `executeOnThread` variants (one for `pthread_t` and one for `pid_t` style thread ids) that take a `std::function<void()>` (for C++), or a `void(*)(void*)` function pointer and `void*` parameter (for C), and `SIGUSR1` that thread to execute the passed function in a `sigaction` that you also setup to perform relevant synchronization with the calling thread. It's handy to be able to use the thread-dependent APIs like pthread_self, gettid, backtrace, getrusage, etc. without devising a custom execution scheme each time.

**2** - `SYS_rt_tgsigqueueinfo` is a low level syscall meant for implementing `sigqueue`/`pthread_sigqueue`, rather than application use, but is still a documented API, and we're using it to implement another variant of `sigqueue`, so fair game IMHO.

Comment: Some interesting ideas but I think my simple though crude moethod is more effective.

Comment: Sure, having a common thread creation function is not viable for a lot of legacy projects which may have with many different dependencies, some binary though.

Comment: The thread ID of a thread does not provide information about the significance of that thread to the program -- what is its purpose, what data does it manipulate, what synchronization objects does it interact with -- so the question is mostly moot in the first place.  There is little or no safe *use* for the information sought unless the program is already tracking thread metadata anyway, in which case it should just include the wanted mapping among the data being tracked.

Comment: Or, the conventional method is to just not do it at all.  Programs ordinarily track threads by their `pthread_t` value (which is conventionally called a "thread identifier", but the question uses conflicting terminology).  The kernel's ID number for a thread is rarely used by userspace programs.

Comment: getrusage and backtrace are safe information.
/proc exposes pid_t not pthread_t
Sometimes you have to deal with what you're given (a pid_t tid)

Comment: Idij - can you please provide an example, I face the same problem and don't always have control over pthread_create and have a vector of tids which I need to terminate